# Permissions issues when rsync from GitHub Actions

Tags: linux, github-actions, file-permissions, user-permissions

I setup a GitHub Actions workflow which connects to my Linux production machine via SSH using RSA keypair (the setting looks a bit like [this tutorial](https://zellwk.com/blog/github-actions-deploy/), except I'm trying to create a dedicated Linux user for that, looks to me like it would be the good practice here).

On my Linux machine, I did:

- created a dedicated user `github` with its RSA keypair
- made the `github` user part of the group `www-data`
- changed the permissions recursively of the web projects folder to 772 (users part of the `www-data` group can read, write and execute)

On the GitHub repo side I set up the secrets `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`, `SSH_HOST` and `SSH_USER` (which is `github`).

The GitHub Actions workflow file (the interesting steps of the workflow) look like this:

```
  - name: Install SSH key
    uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
    with:
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      name: id_rsa
      known_hosts: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}

  - name: Adding known hosts
    run: ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

  - name: Copy repository to server with rsync
    run: rsync -avz ./ ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:/home/www/my_project/ --usermap=github:www-data
```

When I rsync the project folder with the `github`user and its keypair from my local machine project folder to `/home/www/my_project/`on my production server just for a test, everything works fine.

However, when I push on the repo and the GitHub Actions workflow is executed, the rsync steps fails on many files with the following errors on many files of my project:
`rsync: [generator] failed to set times on "/home/www/my_project/app/templates/en": Operation not permitted (1)`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few tries comparing the permissions of the overwritten files of the server before and after rsync, I found out that the files copied from the repo by GitHub Actions didn't have the group write permission anymore, so it couldn't be written over anymore.

So we just need to set up the owner, group, files permissions and directory permissions for the copied files when copying, so that they keep the exact same rights that they had before rsync.  We set directory (`D`) and files (`F`) permissions for group `www-data` to `rwx` so that the same users from the `www-data` group can overwrite later. All in all the rsync step becomes:

```
- name: Copy repository to server with rsync
  run: rsync -avz --chown=github:www-data --chmod=Dg=rwx,Fg=rwx ./ ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:/home/www/my_project/
```

Hope that can be of some help to someone else!

EDIT 2023/03/01:
We might also need to ignore the `.git` directory to avoid overwriting it, since it would still exist on GitHub's machine even though if it's gitignored. So rsync step becomes:

```
- name: Copy repository to server with rsync
  run: rsync -avz --exclude '.git' --chown=github:www-data --chmod=Dg=rwx,Fg=rwx ./ ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:/home/www/my_project/
```

Comment: Did you get the `--exclude` to work? I've tried but we are using the `gsutil` CLI so that option doesn't seem to work. Instead we try to use the `-x` command and I'm trying to either ignore the `.git` folder or the `.git/config` file specifically but I'm shown `/entrypoint.sh: eval: line 87: ./.git/.: Permission denied`

Comment: `exclude` is a `rsync` option, not a `gsutil` option AFAIK. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 1):

The first test to do is to check if your `secrets.SSH_HOST` is actually reachable from a GitHub Cloud runner

```yaml
run: curl -v telnet://${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:443
```

(assuming here an HTTPS URL, but replace the 443 port by one relevant to your URL)

Since the connection seems to work, try the same rsync using a GitHub Action instead of a direct `run:`.
For instance: [Rsync Deployments Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/rsync-deployments-action).

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: rsync deployments
      uses: burnett01/rsync-deployments@5.2.1
      with:
        switches: -avzr --delete
        path: ./
        remote_path: /home/www/my_project/
        remote_host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
        remote_user: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
        remote_key: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_KEY }}
```

Check the `-avzt --delete` options first, to make sure they are a good fit for your use-case.

Comment: It's working partly, so some files are effectively replaced on the server. But for SOME of the files, the permission error is raised. So it's not a connection issue. What I wonder is, why the permission behaves differently while testing from my local machine and from GitHub Actions runner, although I'm using the same user in both cases.

Comment: @bolino In that case, a `run: id -a && ls -alrth` to check what permissions are in place for those files might help.

Comment: @bolino Also, I would test that (the `rsync`) with a GitHub action instead: I have edited the answer.